# Play and Pause interval rxjs

Tags: rxjs, intervals, rxjs6

i'm trying to implement play and pause button using Rxjs library.

```
const play$ = fromEvent(playerImplementation, PLAYER_EVENTS.PLAY).pipe(mapTo(true));
const pause$ = fromEvent(playerImplementation, PLAYER_EVENTS.PAUSE).pipe(mapTo(false));
const waiting$ = fromEvent(playerImplementation, PLAYER_EVENTS.WAITING).pipe(mapTo(false));

let counterTime = 0;
const currentTime$ = interval(30).pipe(
 map(()=>counterTime += 30));

const player$ = merge(play$, pause$, waiting$).pipe(
        switchMap(value => (value ? currentTime$ : EMPTY)));

// DIFFERENCE IN RESULTS
currentTime$.subscribe((v)=> console.log("Regular Count " + v)); // get correctly 30,60,90,120...
player$.subscribe((v)=>console.log("Condition Count" + v)); // get wrongly 30,150,270, 390
```

can anyone help in understanding why there is a difference between the results?

Comment: Bad things happen if you use global variables. How could the results be equal if all streams increase the same variable?

Comment: @itays02 can you log your events then ? play$, pause$, waiting$. I don't get what you expect from player$ when you stop your count. You want to freeze the interval two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because I used several subscribers for one observable (player$ observable). I solve this by using **ReplaySubject** instead of **Observable** and by using **multicasting** in order to handle the event in several subscribers, without changing the value.

```
const play$ = fromEvent(playerImplementation, PLAYER_EVENTS.PLAY).pipe(mapTo(true));
const pause$ = fromEvent(playerImplementation, PLAYER_EVENTS.PAUSE).pipe(mapTo(false));
const waiting$ = fromEvent(playerImplementation, PLAYER_EVENTS.WAITING).pipe(mapTo(false));

  let timeCounter = 0;
  const source = Observable.create((obs : Observer<number>)=> {
          interval(30).pipe(
             map(() => timeCounter += 30)).subscribe(obs);
          return () => {};
        });

        // Cast the observable to subject for distributing to several subscribers
        const currentTime$ = source.pipe(multicast(()=> new ReplaySubject(5))).refCount();

  const player$ = merge(play$, pause$, waiting$).pipe(
        switchMap(value => value ? currentTime$ : EMPTY));
```